# Default Argument Values

Tags: python, arguments, default

Check out the following code:

```
def f(x, myList = []):
    myList.append(x)
    return myList
```

> f(6)

returns [6]

while

> f(7)

returns [6, 7]

My question is why it doesn't use the default myList value when no value is specified.

On the other hand, this code works fine

```
def f(x, myList = None):
if myList == None:
    # This WILL allocate a new list on every call to the function.
    myList = []
myList.append(x)
return myList
```

> f(6)

returns [6]

> f(7)

returns [7]

Why in the later case it takes the default argument value but not in the former case?

Answer (score 0):

The default argument is init at the point of defining the function. So for mutable type values, the function calls share the same variable. You can refer [Why are default values shared between objects](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects).